# Directly connecting to ISP switch directly through modem

Tags: networking, router, modem, bridge, dsl

I'm trying to connect to my ISP's switch directly through the DSL modem provided as I **don't** have a **RJ11 to RJ45** converter.

Current setup:
    [ISP Switch]<--->[DSL Modem]<--->[My PC]

I want to configure the DSL modem to operate equivalent to the following setup:
    [ISP Switch]<--->[My PC]

I am aware of the security risks however my use case absolutely requires this setup.

Comment: Beyond a big security risk, this is not something you can do. In the picture you paint above, this is all ISP equipment, and you need to work through them.

Comment: Why not? Modern motherboards can accept DSL connections directly. Some "pass-through" or similar option must be existing within the settings of the regular DSL modem.

Comment: You need to contact your ISP for Bridged Mode. I have that here (ISP Modem, no ISP Switch) and the ISP put it in Bridge mode for me. But then I put in VPN to mitigate the security risk

Comment: Security risk? It used to be a major security risk in WinXP days, but now the computer's OS likely has an integrated firewall which does much the same job as the router's ("ISP modem's") one. Servers are routinely given direct connections and public IP addresses as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP doesn't have a switch at the other end of your DSL line; it has a DSLAM.

You're asking for your modem to just act as a plain modem (transparent bridge). This is often possible. It's possible your modem has web admin UI to let you make this change, but it's best to consult with your ISP before making this change in case there's something about their network that could make this a problem. For example, your PC may be required to do PPPoE if your modem isn't doing it for you.